# How to pass data from swift to objective c using protocol delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I have a project made with objective c.

***objective c -> swift -> return objective c***

To pass the UIImage data in this order, I worked as follows.

However, I succeeded in passing UIImage data from objective c to swift, but failed to UIImage pass data back to objecitve c.

The reason is that the delegate is nil in swift.

I would really appreciate it if you let me know where something went wrong in the code below.

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol imageDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)send: (UIImage *)sendImage;

@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,imageDelegate> {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
    
}
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<imageDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "imagePointer-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()<imageDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
}

- (IBAction)btnPhoto:(id)sender {
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)send: (UIImage *)sendImage {
    _imageView.image = sendImage;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    
    if (pickedImage) {
        NSLog(@"picked : %@", pickedImage);
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    
    ScViewController *scv = [[ScViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScViewController" bundle:nil];
    scv.img = pickedImage;
    NSLog(@"scv.imgView : %@", scv.img);
    [self presentViewController:scv animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

***bridging-header.h***

```
#import"ViewController.h"
```

***ScViewController.swift***

```
import UIKit

@objc class ScViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @objc(img)
    
    var img:UIImage!   
    var arrowImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
    var delegate : imageDelegate!    
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
        
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        imgView.image = img
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnSave(_ sender: Any) {    
        if delegate == nil{
            print("delegate : nil") // I don't know why delegate is nil
        }else{
            delegate.send(imgView.image)
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: "failed to UIImage pass data back to objecitve c"  That's a retain cycle, right?

Comment: You never assign the delegate? I think just after ```scv.img = pickedImage;``` you need ```scv.delegate = self;```

Comment: your swift class does not conform to the protocol. `UIViewController` vs used class `ViewController` or more clean to guess whats going on it could look like `@objc class ScViewController : UIViewController, imageDelegate { ... }` or `@objc class ScViewController : ViewController { ... }` so your swift class follows its very own delegate scheme until now.